# Iteratively reading multiple cvs from different directories into dataframe then write to new csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have hit a wall. So far have the following code:

```
# define variables of each directory to be used
parent_data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Data\\'
orig_data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Data\\Original\\'
new_data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Data\\New\\'

# Create list of original data files from orig_data_dir
orig_data = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(orig_data_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            orig_data.append(file)
# It populates the file names located in the orig_data_dir
# orig_data = ['Test1.csv', 'Test2.csv', 'Test3.csv'] 

# Create list of new data files from new_data_dir
new_data = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(new_data_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            new_data.append(file)
# It populates the file names located in the orig_data_dir
# orig_data = ['Test1_2.csv', 'Test2_2.csv', 'Test3_2.csv']
```

I have three csv files in each directory. The csv files that end with _2.csv have new data I would like to append to the old data into a new csv file for each respective pair. Each csv file has the exact same rows. What I am trying to do is the following:

1. Read Test1.csv and Test1_2.csv into one dataframe using the lists I created (if better way, I am open to this) (next iteration = Test2.csv and Test2_2.csv, etc.)
2. Do some pandas stuff
3. Write new file called Test_Compiled_1.csv (next iteration = Test_Compiled_2.csv, etc.)
4. Repeat until each csv pair from the two directories have been combined into a new csv file for each pair.

EDIT:
I have 1000s of csv files. With that said, i need to:

1. read in the first file pair to the same dataframe:
   1st iteration: Test1.csv located in orig_data_dir and Test1_2.csv located in new_data_dir
2. do pandas stuff
3. write out the populated dataframe to a new file in parent_data_dir
4. Repeat for each file pair

2nd iteration would be: Test2.csv and Test2_2.csv

1000 iteration would be: Test1000.csv and Test1000_2.csv

Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: IIUC, why append to a file first and then split them up again and append to another file?

Comment: @Zanshin it's to keep each file pair seperate from the others as each csv file is associated with a location. I also tried to combine all of them together into one large dataframe before. However, Jupyter Notebook doesn't like it since the combined file size is large (GB's).

Comment: When you import into your notebook nothing happens to their location. In the end you want to combine the files, which contain the same string in their filenames, into a dataframe, correct?

Comment: @Zanshin please see edit above. I hope this clarifies desirable outcome.

Comment: This is too broad, the writing of the endresult you can find on this site. Steps 1 and 2 you can do with my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best advice it to let the same names to the  files in each directory, 
and let only useful data in these directories. Here is a solution for different names:

```
for filename in os.listdir(orig_data_dir):
    name,ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    filename_2 = new_data_dir+name+'_2'+ext # construct new filename from old
    if os.path.isfile(filename_2):
        df_Orig=pd.read_csv(orig_data_dir+filename,index_col=0)
        df_New=pd.read_csv(filename_2,index_col=0)
        df_Orig.append(df_New).to_csv(orig_data_dir+filename)
```

Here I accumulate the result in the Original file. Only one loop is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. This works for all steps as i was looking for. I added an exception for when some files have no data. I added this to your code input.

Comment: I don't think it's the best way. Empty data is not as such a problem, and it's better to ensure elsewhere (at creation) that  Original is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would help you:

```
from itertools import chain
import fnmatch

paths = ('/path/to/directory/one/', '/path/to/directory/two/', 'etc.', 'etc.')

file1 = []
file2 = []

for path, dirs, files in chain.from_iterable(os.walk(path) for path in paths):
    for file in files:
    if file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*1*.csv'):
        file1.append(file)
    if file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*2*.csv'):
        file2.append(file)

To create your dataframes you would do something like this;

df_file1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(file1[0], sep=';')), pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(file1[1], sep=';'))], ignore_index=True)

df_file2 etc.
```

Note; the 'sep' in your csv might be different.

EDIT; I've changed `endswith` with `fnmatch.filter`, you can now use any pattern you like for matching the files you need in the different directories.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This is helpful in understanging how to access the directories iteratively. To clarify, I am going to be iterating over 1,000s of csv files (ones ending without "_2" and ones with "_2" which make up each respective pair). I just used three in each directory as an example. With that said, i am looking for a solution that will iteratively place each pair into a dataframe and then write the result to a file and repeat this until there are no pairs left to iterate over. Hope this helps clarify what i am seeking. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Then your question is unclear. You should update. In your example you have the csv's ending on  '1.csv' and this solution would work.

Comment: On what will you match the files then? Parts of the filename that are similar? Not want they end on?

Comment: i will be matching entire filenames and distinguishing the original data from the new data by what they end in.

Comment: Thank you @Zanshin. Your solution works for steps 1 and 2 as you said. I appreciate your efforts.